# Step from custom Jenkins plugin throwing step must be called with a body

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I developed a custom Jenkins plugin that provides a step "mystep" for my pipelines.

After [this PR](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/pull/370) was merged my step fails with this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: mystep step must be called with a body
```

My step doesn't require a body: `mystep param1: "somevalue"`. It is implemented extending `Step`

```
class MyStepStep @DataBoundConstructor constructor(private val param1: String) : Step() {
    @set:DataBoundSetter
    var param1: String? = null

    @Throws(Exception::class)
    override fun start(context: StepContext): StepExecution {
```

How can I indicate that it doesn't require a body so that it doesn't fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the `StepDescriptor` implementation had overwritten the value `takesImplicitBlockArgument` setting true. Back to false and everything started working again:

```
abstract class MyStepDescriptor : StepDescriptor() {

    override fun takesImplicitBlockArgument(): Boolean {
        return false
    }
```

Comment: "Back to false and everything started working again", yet the code snippet returns "true" -- so it's not the solution. 
I face this issue -- on Groovy 2.83  [AcquireSemaphore](https://github.com/jenkinsci/concurrent-step-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/com/github/topikachu/jenkins/concurrent/semaphore/AcquireStep.java#L83) works, while on 2.89 does break when without the block/body.